# Why can't I assign null to decimal with ternary operator?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can't understand why this won't work

```
decimal? compRetAmount = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLineCompRetAmt.Text) 
    ? decimal.Parse(txtLineCompRetAmt.Text.Replace(",","")) 
    : null;
```

Comment: We're not mind readers, what doesn't work?

Comment: It's called the conditional operator, not the ternary operator

Comment: @JakubKonecki although it is clear. It's always good to provide as much info as possible. In this case a compilation error

Comment: @ThomasLevesque - isn't conditional operator an example of ternary operator, as it has 3 parts?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, From msdn, `One operator, the conditional operator (?:), takes three operands and is the sole ternary operator in C#.`

Comment: Sure, it's **a** ternary operator, but that's not its name, that's its type

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Because `null` is of type `object` (effectively untyped) and you need to assign it to a typed object.

This should work:

```
decimal? compRetAmount = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLineCompRetAmt.Text) 
         ? decimal.Parse(txtLineCompRetAmt.Text.Replace(",","")) 
         : (decimal?)null;
```

or this is a bit better:

```
decimal? compRetAmount = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLineCompRetAmt.Text) 
         ? decimal.Parse(txtLineCompRetAmt.Text.Replace(",","")) 
         : default(decimal?);
```

Here is the MSDN link for the [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/default-value-expressions) keyword.

Comment: The best response is the one that doesn't just answer but informs and educates.. nice one slugster

Answer (score 7):

Don't use `decimal.Parse`.

`Convert.ToDecimal` will return 0 if it is given a null string. `decimal.Parse` will throw an ArgumentNullException if the string you want to parse is null.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
decimal? compRetAmount = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLineCompRetAmt.Text) ? 
                         decimal.Parse(txtLineCompRetAmt.Text.Replace(",", "")) : 
                         (decimal?) null;
```

The problem is that the compiler does not know what type `null`has. So you can just cast it to `decimal?`

Answer (score 3):

```
decimal? compRetAmount = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLineCompRetAmt.Text) ?  
                          decimal.Parse(txtLineCompRetAmt.Text.Replace(",","")) : 
                          (decimal?)null;
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the compiler can't infer the best type from the operands of the conditional operator.

When you write `condition ? a : b`, there must be an implicit conversion from the type of `a` to the type of `b`, or from the type of `b` to the type of `a`. The compiler will then infer the type of the whole expression as the target type of this conversion. The fact that you assign it to a variable of type `decimal?` is never considered by the compiler. In your case, the types of `a` and `b` are `decimal` and some unknown reference or nullable type. The compiler can't guess what you mean, so you need to help it:

```
decimal? compRetAmount = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLineCompRetAmt.Text)
                             ? decimal.Parse(txtLineCompRetAmt.Text.Replace(",",""))
                             : default(decimal?);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the first part to `decimal?`

```
decimal? compRetAmount = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLineCompRetAmt.Text) 
    ? (decimal?)decimal.Parse(txtLineCompRetAmt.Text.Replace(",","")) 
    : null;
```

Comment: That wouldn't make a difference. A `decimal` can be put into a `decimal?`.

Comment: "The output type of the ternary operator is the type of the first part": this is not true... it can be the type of either the first or second part, depending on which conversions exist between them

Comment: You can assign a `decimal` to a `decimal?` without explicit casting.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque - cheers, Thomas. I always thought that's the case. That's why I love SO - you can always learn sth new.