# Converting bool? to bool in assignment

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, nullable

I have a scenario where we have a data contract file Property auto generated as non-nullable bool property like below.

```
public bool IsAlive { get; set;}
```

But I am trying to assign a nullable bool and hence compiler shows me error as to can not convert from nullable to non nullable.

So, I have two ways to resolve this error, but just curious is there any difference at all in these two ways? Because I realize both are same as default value even if we don't set anything to bool is false?

```
IsAlive = myDaddy.Status ?? false;
IsAlive = (bool)myDaddy.Status;
```

Comment: Your second attempt will throw an error if `Status` is null. The first one will give `false` if the status is null.

Comment: do you understand the difference in both lines you posted.. the first one is ternary think of it as an inline `if else` so `IsAlive = myDaddy.Status if true else return false` the second on is casting myDaddy.Status as a bool but if it's already declared as a bool then the second one is pointless especially if the value is null

Comment: Have you considered making IsAlive nullable?  Also gives you a third point of view, true, false and unknown.

Comment: @JStevens: That's exactly what I wanted to do, nut lol don't know how to do as I am new to project :-) As you rightly said, we have EVERYwhere declared it as nullable but I am surprised only in this file damn, its non null. Anyway I am afraid to talk to my architect as to where to change this :p I feel silly lol, but fair enough, I am new to project and they have sooo many settings on where they do :) Will find out! I think what you suggest is the ideal solution

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9308524/109702

Comment: IsAlive = myDaddy?.Status ?? false; //even better yet

Answer (score 0):

The Status is probably a `bool?` type which is not `bool` but a `Nullable<bool>` type.

`?` addition is a **syntactic sugar** for `Nullable<Type>`.
Thus you cannot explicitly convert them into that type but you can use the `Value` method that comes as part of the `Nullable<>` generic class.

The two method differ the `Nullable<bool>` thus the compiler yells at you, that it can not convert it into `bool` type.

You should refactor those lines with the assumption of a way to convert those two assignment to give a result for `bool` or change your `IsAlive` variable into `bool?` type.

**Solution #1:**

```
IsAlive = myDaddy.Status.GetValueOrDefault();
IsAlive = (myDaddy.Status.HasValue ? myDaddy.Status.Value : false);
```

**Solution #2:**

```
public bool? IsAlive { get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

`bool?` is the short hand for `Nullable<bool>` which uses `Nullable<T>` struct. See documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx).

Because `bool?` is of the `Nullable<T>` type it has two helpful parameters. HasValue and Value.

You could use the those properties in this way to set a regular bool with the appropriate value.

```
bool? status = null;
bool isAlive;

if(status.HasValue)
{
    //A value is set and can be True or False
    isAlive = status.Value; 
}
else 
{
    //Nullable bool has no value, there for bool value should be false.
    isAlive = false;    
}
```

So your code could look like any of these:

```
IsAlive = myDaddy.Status.HasValue ? myDaddy.Status.Value : false;
```

or

```
if(myDaddy.Status.HasValue)
{
   IsAlive = myDaddy.Status.Value;
}
else
{
  IsAlive = false;
}
```