# Using GetDecimal gives an error in condition expression

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, dbnull

Hi I am using `GetDecimal()` but it gives an error in condition expression.

```
Data = varCmd.IsDBNull(2) ? null : varCmd.GetDecimal(2)
```

As this gives an error saying `"Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between string and decimal "`. What can be used as default value for `GetDecimal()`? Any help?

Comment: Similar issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308443/why-cant-i-assign-null-to-decimal-with-ternary-operator & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289359/assign-null-to-decimal-using-ternary-operator. Use `(decimal?) null` if `Data` is `Nullable<decimal>` type.

Comment: What's "Data" type?

Comment: its a model item as decimal field

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto those options are not helping me here. I tried them.

Comment: Can you add your database table definition and the select statement - this error would indicate that you are not reading a decimal value.

Comment: I rechecked it column Data is on type Decimal(18,0) in DB

Comment: from string **and** decimal? Can you please write the correct error message? If it is "to", not "and", are you referring to the right column? The 3rd column is the decimal one?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I checked the select statement in my stored proc. Its a 3 rd column and theexact error message is "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between string and decimal "

Comment: Note: You can't add `null` value to a non-nullable `decimal`. Try using default value instead of null if `Data` is `decimal` & not `decimal?`: `Data = varCmd.IsDBNull(2) ? (decimal)0 : decimal.Parse(varCmd.GetString(2))`.

Comment: Note for the future: Be precise when writing up your question, the alluded error message is not the actual one. Thus the answer provided is now wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is this part:

```
Data = varCmd.IsDBNull(2) ? null : varCmd.GetDecimal(2)
                            ^-+^   ^----------+-------^
                              |               |
                              |               +-- Decimal type
                              +-- not a Decimal type
```

The expression fails to compile because the compiler is not able to deduce that in order to make it work, it would have to make the last part a nullable Decimal, thus it tries to find a type that can hold `null`, lands on `string`, and thus the error message.

You need to specify that you want a nullable decimal as the result, **assuming** `Data` is also nullable decimal.

If it is, this will work:

```
Data = varCmd.IsDBNull(2) ? (Decimal?)null : varCmd.GetDecimal(2)
```

If it isn't, then you need to decide what to store into `Data` if the column is `null` (`DBNull`), probably `0`:

```
Data = varCmd.IsDBNull(2) ? 0 : varCmd.GetDecimal(2)
```

Comment: `Data = varCmd.IsDBNull(2) ? 0 : varCmd.GetDecimal(2)` potentially resulting conversion error `int` to `decimal`. `Data = varCmd.IsDBNull(2) ? (decimal)0 : varCmd.GetDecimal(2)` ensures same data type for both true & false conditions.

Comment: No, `0` is auto-convertible to decimal so the resulting type is decimal. The whole problem here stems from the fact that a ternary operator cannot have different types for its two result expressions. Using `0` will in fact use `Decimal.Zero` "constant" internally, so this is perfectly safe to do.